# Query displays incorrect ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server

The output that is needed is attached as an image. The code I currently have displays Arrival Date and Departure Date correctly, but the Guest names displayed are not exactly the same as the image. The image displays first names in a random order while the last names are ordered correctly.

```
SELECT UPPER(substring(GLASTNAME,1,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(GLASTNAME,2,len(GLASTNAME)-1)) + ', '+ 
        UPPER(substring(GFIRSTNAME,1,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(GFIRSTNAME,2,len(GFIRSTNAME)-1)) AS Guest,

        FORMAT(ARRIVAL_DATE, 'dddd MM/dd/yy') AS [Arrival Date],
        FORMAT(DateADD(d,NUMDAYS, ARRIVAL_DATE),'dddd MM/dd/yy') AS [Departure Date]
FROM guestWH g INNER JOIN reservationWH r ON g.RNUM = r.RNUM
    INNER JOIN packageWH p ON r.P_ID = p.P_ID 
WHERE NUMDAYS = 5 OR NUMDAYS = 6 OR NUMDAYS = 7
ORDER BY [Arrival Date] ASC
```

[Correct answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW9g2.png)

My current output looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR8E8.jpg

Comment: Please post data as text, not pictures. It makes debugging - and thus answering your question - a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You need to order by guest and then [Arrival Date] - so you can try below using `1 which means it will order by first column which is guestname in your case and then [Arrival Date]`

```
SELECT UPPER(substring(GLASTNAME,1,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(GLASTNAME,2,len(GLASTNAME)-1)) + ', '+ 
        UPPER(substring(GFIRSTNAME,1,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(GFIRSTNAME,2,len(GFIRSTNAME)-1)) AS Guest,

        FORMAT(ARRIVAL_DATE, 'dddd MM/dd/yy') AS [Arrival Date],
        FORMAT(DateADD(d,NUMDAYS, ARRIVAL_DATE),'dddd MM/dd/yy') AS [Departure Date]
FROM guestWH g INNER JOIN reservationWH r ON g.RNUM = r.RNUM
    INNER JOIN packageWH p ON r.P_ID = p.P_ID 
WHERE NUMDAYS = 5 OR NUMDAYS = 6 OR NUMDAYS = 7
ORDER BY 1, [Arrival Date] ASC
```

Comment: This code doesn't output the same as the correct answer shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW9g2.png

Comment: where you found the difference @MateoLeon

Comment: The code you provided with "ORDER BY 1" orders it by their name, but the correct answer in the image orders by last name with a random order for first name. i.e. Redding, Harry Redding, Marcie Redding,Antonio. While my code gives Redding, Antonio Redding, Harry Redding, Marcie